# Need an SQL query for this input and output

Tags: sql, pivot

Need an SQL query for the following:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome Kaushik Ghosh. Please edit your question as it did not render the images properly, and also include what you have tried.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this

```
Select id,
  max(col1) as col1,
  max(col2) as col2,
  ...
From your_table
Group by id;
```